# Removed steps in ASP.NET Wizard reappear after postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, wizard

I have an ASP.NET Wizard with multiple steps where I need to skip over some steps based on certain flags. I was thinking I could use the Wizard.WizardSteps.Remove(WizardStepBase) method to get rid of the steps that aren't necessary since they cannot be disabled.

I have five steps specified in the markup when I first navigate to the page containing the wizard.

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" OnNextButtonClick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
    <!-- Navigation and Header templates go here -->
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="StepA" runat="server">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="StepB" runat="server">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="StepC" runat="server">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="StepD" runat="server">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="StepE" runat="server">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
        </asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

- Step A: index = 0
- Step B: index = 1
- Step C: index = 2
- Step D: index = 3
- Step E: index = 4

I remove steps C and D using the Wizard.WizardSteps.Remove(WizardStepBase) method. If I check the indexes again I have the following:

- Step A: index = 0
- Step B: index = 1
- Step C: index = -1 (not found; it was removed)
- Step D: index = -1 (not found; it was removed)
- Step E: index = 2

This is what I want. If click the next button, a postback occurs and I should be able to navigate from Step A to Step B, Step B to Step E within the NextButtonClick event handler and Step C and Step D aren't shown.

The problem is, the steps reappear after the postback so it seems that even when ViewState is enabled, I'm going to have to remove steps C and D on every postback. I would expect that the Wizard would remember which steps were in it's collection. Is there a specific reason why that isn't the case?

Here's the source code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Omitted: Setting values of StepAEnabled, etc. based on business rules.
        // Just hard-code for this example
        var stepAEnabled = true;
        var stepBEnabled = true;
        var stepCEnabled = false;
        var stepDEnabled = false;
        var stepEEnabled = true;

        if (!stepAEnabled)
            Wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(StepA);

        if (!stepBEnabled)
            Wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(StepB);

        if (!stepCEnabled)
            Wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(StepC);

        if (!stepDEnabled)
            Wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(StepD);

        if (!stepEEnabled)
            Wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(StepE);
    }

    // When !IsPostBack, totalSteps == 3
    // When IsPostback, totalSteps == 5
    var totalSteps = Wizard1.WizardSteps.Count;
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing the WizardSteps you can use `ActiveStepIndex` property to skip the steps e.g. to jump from Step B (index 1) to Step E you can set the ActiveStepIndex to 4 in `OnNextButtonClick`

Comment: Could you post the code-behind?
It sounds like you have to check for `IsPostBack` else you will end up with the original setup of the page, which contains all the wizard steps.

Comment: @FrankWitte I've added my sample code to reproduce the problem. As a workaround, I moved the code to remove the steps outside the block that checks IsPostback and moved the flags indicating which steps are enabled to Boolean properties that are stored in ViewState so they are retained between postbacks (the actual determination of these values is done by executing a database query, which I had omitted).

Comment: @MohsinMehmood The reason I don't want to use the ActiveStepIndex is because I have a progress indicator on my page that indicates "Step X of Y", where X = Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex + 1 and Y = Wizard1.WizardSteps.Count. WizardSteps is a collection which supports add/remove operations and I cannot set the Visible property on specific steps because that causes an exception to be thrown. Manipulating ActiveStepIndex will make this calculation less straighforward.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to delete the steps you want on the `Page_LoadComplete` cycle as below:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (WizardStepBase step in wizard.WizardSteps)
  {

    if (YOUR LOGIC)
    {
      wizard1.WizardSteps.Remove(step);
    }            

   }
}
```